# Where to find documentation for `whois` command options?

Tags: macos, command-line

macOS has `whois` command available. Running it without any argument shows the following:

```
usage: whois [-aAbfgiIklmPQrRS] [-c country-code | -h hostname] [-p port] name ...
```

Here, the `-c`, `-h`, and `-p` options have description. However, no description is available for the rest of the shown options `-aAbfgiIklmPQrRS`.

How can I find the documentation for the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can read the man page for `whois` command by running the following in the Terminal:

`man whois`

The man page for a command is the all-encompassing document, listing all the available options for the command. Man pages are generally available for all the available external commands. To locate installed man page(s) for a command, run the following:

`man -aw <command>`

To read a specific man page for a command, (in case more than one are listed on running the above) use the absolute path for the man page.

---

While viewing the man page for a command, you can use the following keyboard shortcuts to navigate:

- <kbd>j</kbd>: Scroll down one line at a time.
- <kbd>k</kbd>: Scroll up one line at a time.
- <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>: Scroll down one page at a time.
- <kbd>b</kbd>: Scroll up one page at a time.
- `/search`: To search for the keyword `search`. Use `n` to navigate to the next match.
- <kbd>q</kbd>: Quit the man page viewer and return to the shell.

Comment: Addendum to the shortcuts: `/search` only searches *forwards*, and you can also issue empty `/` "searches" to go the next match. If you use `?search`, you can search backwards, and bare `?` goes to the previous match. `/` and `?` inter-operate; after issuing either `/search` or `?search`, both bare `/` and bare `?` will use `search`.

Comment: Plus one for the mini-primer on how to use less.

Comment: While I agree with @fd0 , mentioning that this behavior is specific to less (and is essentially up to `MANPAGER`) might be worthwile

Comment: @fd0, beat me to it. I was going to suggest "man less" to learn about pagination, searching, and stuff. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Right-click on the name of the command and choose Open man Page
or ⌃⇧⌘? with the name of the command selected.

[image]

This opens the manual for the command in a new tab or window. You can browse this document using the scroll wheel as normal and perform regular operations like ⌘F for find.

[image]

This shortcut is also available on Touch Bar without needing to select the command name first.

[image: Touch Bar screenshot]

Comment: Holy crap, I never knew that, great tip! (Yeah I know this type of comment is frowned upon but just once maybe?)

Answer (score 5):

If you are keyboard ninja and do not wish to use the Mouse/Trackpad, there's an easy way to locate the man page(s) for a command.

Invoke the search under Terminal's Help menu by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, and type in the command. The search looks for the man pages corresponding to the search term and lists them under Man Pages section.

[image]

Select and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the desired item to view the man page in the main window.

Comment: That's technically even one keystroke less than using the `man` in the shell